# Why are labels and buttons drawing background

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nsview

As the title suggests:

[image: Labels and the gradient buttons are skipping the color of their superview]

Labels and the gradient buttons are skipping the color of their superview. Note that it's not bordered or drawing its own background, but rather showing transparent.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with my code. It works fine if I change the label color. but I cant change the color of buttons so I'm stuck with that

Comment: This is a known problem. Take your pick: [Search SO for nspopover background](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=nspopover%20background)

Comment: Thanks. Had to change the appearance to Aqua